# Is there a way to get my code to do the same but with ng-show/hide?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have this small snippet of code, which works perfectly the way i want it to, but i can't find anywhere how to get the same effect with the use of Angular instead of jQuery. Ideally it would use ng-show or ng-hide.so far I haven't been able to find the solution, and most tutorials i could find were vague or didn't explain the things i actually need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="testjs.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#div1").show(1000);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#div1").hide(1000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Do you want to print something on your shirt? </h3>
<input id="show" class="xd" type="checkbox">Yes</input>
<input id="hide" class="xd" type="checkbox">No</input>

<script>
$('input.xd').on('change', function() {
    $('input.xd').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
</script>
<style>
#div1 {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<div id="div1">
<div>
    First name:
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" data-ng-model="firstname"/> {{ 
firstname }}
    <br />
    Last name:
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" ng-model="lastname" /> {{ lastname }}
    <br />
    Number:
    <input type="text" maxlength="3" ng-model="number"/> {{ number }}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'
```

and

```
  function showMe (box) {

    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    var vis = "none";
    for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
        if(chboxs[i].checked){
         vis = "block";
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;


}
```

Comment: You wrote `so far I haven't been able to find the solution, and most tutorials i could find were vague or didn't explain the things i actually need.` What I find vague is your question. There are tons of examples for things like this in AngularJS. Better try harder before ask for help.

Comment: where is your angularjs code?